# Probability current density : Isn't there something wrong with this proof?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there something wrong with the following proof (see below)? To me, it seems like the third line should show $$\frac{dP_{ab}}{dt}=-\int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial t}J(x,t)dx$$
Am I missing something obvious?

---

[image]

Comment: Yes in the very first equation after the horizontal line, the right absolute value line, |, is missing.

Comment: @Chris: That's just a typo. My main concern is the swapping of a $\partial x$ for a $\partial t$ in the third line.

Comment: Ok.  I'd be more inclined to think the last equation on line 2 is wrong.  I think it should be the partial with respect to x, not t.

Comment: Griffith's 2nd Ed problem 1.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at line 2, we have an integral set equal to:

[image]

We then must note that $J(x,t)$ is defined as the negative of:

[image]

So the last equation on line 2 should be:  $-\frac{\partial J(x,t)}{\partial x}$ as opposed to $-\frac{\partial J(x,t)}{\partial t}$.