# current density in 1-d

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-current

I have a slight problem with the notion of the current density in one dimension. For example the probability current in 1-d given by:
$J(x) = -\frac{1}{m} Im(-i\psi^*\partial_x \psi)$

calculation the total current $I$ from the density is achieved by integrating the density over some surface through which we would like to find the current. So what surface can i take in a 1-d system? or is it that in 1-d $J$ ~ $I$?

thanks in advance

Comment: It may help to replace the word "surface" in this case with "edge" or "boundary." Ask yourself *What is the boundary of a 1-dimensional interval?* (Try drawing it out.) Also, note that the dimension the surface of some space is of one fewer dimension than the space itself.

Comment: There is no physical notion associated to a "total current". There is only a probability current $J(x,t)$. There is only a notion of total probability which is $1$, if the "wavefunction" is normalizable. See this previous [post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56502/6316). In this post, You may be interested by the expression $ \frac{d P_{ab}(t)}{dt} = J(a,t)-J(b,t)$. Take $a = -\infty, b=+\infty$. If the wave function is normalizable, then $P_{-\infty, +\infty}(t)$ equals $1$, and so, we must have $J(+\infty, t) - J(-\infty, t)=0$.

Comment: ... This is in fact just the integration of $J(t)$ on the oriented boundary of the $1$ dimension space. This boundary ($-\infty, +\infty$) is your "surface"